# How to make 3d text to appear on camera view in blender

Tags: blender

I am creating a 3d text on blender2.8 but I am having a hard time trying to make it appear on the camera view.

I have tried rotating and scaling the camera but it doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The camera object is the focal point for the final image, like in real life, if you want to get more in the picture you need to move the camera back or zoom out.

With the camera close -

[image: close camera]

With the camera far away -

[image: far camera]

To zoom out, you reduce the camera's focal length.

[image: camera settings]